# Plot ecdf and cdf for N(0,1) by using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r

I want to draw ecdf for this data

```
x<-rnorm(50,1,1)
```

and cdf for standard normal distribution by using ggplot2 in R, and find the max distance between them, how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What have you tried so far?   The community will help you solve problems you encounter in writing your own code, but is much less willing to write your code for you.

Comment: The max dist is `ks.test(x, pnorm)`.

Answer (score 3):

The distance between an empirical distribution and a reference distribution is given by the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test statistic, `D`.

```
set.seed(2021)
x <- rnorm(50, 1, 1)

ks.test(x, pnorm)$statistic
#        D 
#0.4208551
```

### Base R plot

```
plot(ecdf(x))
curve(pnorm, from = -10, to = 10, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

### `ggplot` plot

```
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(x, y = ecdf(x)(x))
ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) +
  stat_ecdf() +
  stat_function(fun = pnorm)
```

[image]